# Classic asp creating array from recordset error

Tags: sql-server, arrays, asp-classic

I am getting the error of:

> ```
> Category:Microsoft VBScript runtime 
> Description:Subscript out of range
> Line:46
> ```

from the following code:

```vbs
<%
''*************************************************************************
''Created Date: 10/28/13
''Created By:   NG
''Description:  Test page for new highcharts charts replacing ChartFX for business trends
''History:      N/A
''*************************************************************************

'OPEN CONNECTION TO SQL SERVER
'-create objects
Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set adoRsGraph = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set adoCom = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
'-open connection

'scon = "FILE NAME=" & server.MapPath("/d_support") & "\cfn_datastore_heracles.udl"
scon = "FILE NAME=" & server.MapPath("/d_support") & "\cfn_datastore.udl"

adoCon.Open sCon

adoCom.CommandType= 4
adoCom.ActiveConnection = sCon
'GET RECORDSET DATA NEEDED TO FILL IN THE ACCOUNT BALANCE CHART
'-call stored proc to retrieve data

    adoCom.CommandText="sp_Chart_AccountBalance3"
    adoCom.Parameters(1) = 21820

adoRsGraph.CursorLocation = 3
adoRsGraph.Open adoCom

dim xAxisData()
dim yAxisData()
j = 0               
    adoRsGraph.MoveFirst            
if adoRsGraph.EOF = false then

    Do Until adoRsGraph.EOF
        xAxisData(j) = adoRsGraph("Value")
        yAxisData(j) = adoRsGraph("Date")

        j = j + 1
        adoRsGraph.MoveNext
    Loop
end if
%>
```

I am not entirely sure what Line 46 is, but I assume it must be within my loop through the recordset. I have done traces when running this and see that the sproc is being called correctly, and when running within SQL server it contains record in the dataset, so why wouldn't my loop work to assign values to the arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created two arrays, but you can't use them until you have given them a size.

Use the `ReDim` command to resize the arrays right before putting the values in them:

```
ReDim xAxisData(j)
ReDim yAxisData(j)
```

Comment: thank you for the response, are you referring to inside the Loop to use reDim or right before it?  Is it necessary to reDim the array everytime the loop iterates to add another index to the array?  Disregard, i got it figured thank you very much!